# Кавычки при использовании curl

Tags: curl

В чём отличие двух запросов?

```
curl -X GET 'https://example.com/' -H 'authorization: 12345'
```

Почему следующий случай не работает и не воспринимает `authorization`, отдавая: `{"detail":"user not authorized"}`

```
curl -X GET "https://example.com/" -H "authorization: 12345"
```

Comment: у вас ведь ошибка была не с 12345, какими-то более хитрыми символами

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov понял, окей.